# javascript и несколько input text

Tags: javascript, html

Прошу помочь решить проблему.
Есть два поля ввода, которые затем формируют список.
Но в случае со вторым полем ввода не записываются строки в колонку, т. е. сама строка появляется, но введеного в нее текста нет.

Не могу найти причину, прошу подсказать.

Если задать для второго поля ввода (input type="password") вместо (input type="text"), то все начинает работать корректно, но появляется другая проблема -- все что мы вводим в строку "password" скрывается, что неудобно.

Во вложении архив, необходимо смотреть листы "nеw recept.html/js"

```js
$(function (){

var $list, $stranica, $newItemForm1, $newItemForm2, $newItemButton;
  $newItemForm1 = $('#newItemForm1');
  $newItemForm2 = $('#newItemForm2');
  $list = $('ul#one');
  $stranica = $('ul#two');

 $newItemForm1.on('submit', function(e) {       // При отправке нового пункта
    e.preventDefault();                         // Предотвращаем отправку формы
    var text1 = $('input:text').val();           // Получаем значение текстового поля
    $list.append('<li>' + text1 + '</li>');      // Добавляем элемент в конец списка
    $('input:text').val('');                    // Очищаем поле ввода
  });


$newItemForm2.on('submit', function(e) {       // При отправке нового пункта
    e.preventDefault();                         // Предотвращаем отправку формы
    var text2 = $('input:text').val();           // Получаем значение текстового поля
    $stranica.append('<li>' + text2 + '</li>');      // Добавляем элемент в конец списка
    $('input:text').val('');                    // Очищаем поле ввода
  });


  });
```

```css
body{
background-image: url(images/fon777.jpg);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-attachment: fixed;
background-position: center top;
font-family:'Roboto Roboto-Regular', sans-serif;
}



@font-face {
font-family: Roboto Regular;
src: url(Roboto-Regular.ttf);
}

.str{
width: 970px;
height: auto;
margin: 0 auto;
background-color: #efefef;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-attachment: scroll;
background-position: center top;

}

h4, h6{
 text-align: right;
 font-style: italic; 
}

h3{
 text-align: center;
 font-weight: bold;
 font-style: italic; 
 text-decoration: underline;
}

h1{
 text-align: center;
 font-weight: bold;
 font-style: italic; 
}

div.lin {
  border-bottom: 2px solid #5bc0de;
}

h5{
color: black; 
}

.btn-group{
margin: 0px;
padding: 1px 1px 1px 1px;

border: 10px;
}

#content1 
{
 height: 100%;
 overflow: auto;
 text-transform: uppercase;
}

#ot{
 padding: 10px;
 border-radius: 25px; 
}

#carousel-example-generic1,
#carousel-example-generic2,
#carousel-example-generic3
{
 margin: 10px;
    float: left;
}

@keyframes animate{ 
from { 
opacity: 0; 
transform: translateY(-100%) 
} 
to { 
opacity: 1; 
transform: unset; 
} 
} 

#pic{
border-radius: 25px; 
animation-name: animate; 
animation-duration: 500ms; 
opacity: 1.0; 
}

.colon 
{
 width: 290px;
 float: left;
 margin: 10px;
 text-align: center;
    border-radius: 25px; 
}

div.colon:hover {
background-color: #b1c6b2;}
```

```html
<html>

<head>

<title>???</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="2hfp1SzUoho7/TsGGGDaFdsuuDL0LX2hnUp6VkX3CUQ2K4K+xjboZdsXyp4oUHZj" crossorigin="anonymous">

<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
<link href="csstitle.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
 <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">
</head>

<body>
<div class="str">
<h1><i>???</i></h1>
<hr />
<a href="title.html"><button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-sm btn-block">Вернуться на главную страницу</button></a>
<hr />

<div id="ingridients">
<h3>Ингредиенты:</h3>

<ul id="one">
</ul>
 
<form id="newItemForm1">
    <input type="text" id="itemDescription1" placeholder="Добавьте описание" />
    <input type="submit" id="add1" value="добавить" />
</form>
    
</div>


<hr />

<div id="prigotovlenie">
<h3>Приготовление:</h3>

<ul id="two">
</ul>

<form id="newItemForm2">
    <input type="text" id="itemDescription2" placeholder="Добавьте описание" />
    <input type="submit" id="add2" value="добавить" />
</form>

<h5 id="ot">Приятного аппетита!</h5>
</div>


<a href="title.html"><button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-sm btn-block">Вернуться на главную страницу</button></a>
</div>

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js" integrity="sha384-THPy051/pYDQGanwU6poAc/hOdQxjnOEXzbT+OuUAFqNqFjL+4IGLBgCJC3ZOShY" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.2.0/js/tether.min.js" integrity="sha384-Plbmg8JY28KFelvJVai01l8WyZzrYWG825m+cZ0eDDS1f7d/js6ikvy1+X+guPIB" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.4/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="VjEeINv9OSwtWFLAtmc4JCtEJXXBub00gtSnszmspDLCtC0I4z4nqz7rEFbIZLLU" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="new recept.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[введите сюда описание изображения](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lySPB.png)

Comment: я подозреваю, что проблема в этой строчке `var text2 = $('input:text')`. Скорее всего, Jquery ищет первое совпадение, что и является первым инпутом.

Comment: Логично. Вопрос: как разделить эти два input:text?

Comment: использовать айдишники... см. ответ

Comment: Спасибо!
Исправил с  var text2 = $('input:text').val();  на  (var text2 = $('#itemDescription2').val();) и заработало!

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(function (){

var $list, $stranica, $newItemForm1, $newItemForm2, $newItemButton;
  $newItemForm1 = $('#newItemForm1');
  $newItemForm2 = $('#newItemForm2');
  $list = $('ul#one');
  $stranica = $('ul#two');

 $newItemForm1.on('submit', function(e) {       // При отправке нового пункта
    e.preventDefault();                         // Предотвращаем отправку формы
    var text1 = $('input:text').val();           // Получаем значение текстового поля
    $list.append('<li>' + text1 + '</li>');      // Добавляем элемент в конец списка
    $('input:text').val('');                    // Очищаем поле ввода
  });


$newItemForm2.on('submit', function(e) {       // При отправке нового пункта
    e.preventDefault();                         // Предотвращаем отправку формы
    var text2 = $('#itemDescription2').val();           // Получаем значение текстового поля
    $stranica.append('<li>' + text2 + '</li>');      // Добавляем элемент в конец списка
    $('#itemDescription2').val('');                    // Очищаем поле ввода
  });


  });
```

```css
body{
background-image: url(images/fon777.jpg);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-attachment: fixed;
background-position: center top;
font-family:'Roboto Roboto-Regular', sans-serif;
}



@font-face {
font-family: Roboto Regular;
src: url(Roboto-Regular.ttf);
}

.str{
width: 970px;
height: auto;
margin: 0 auto;
background-color: #efefef;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-attachment: scroll;
background-position: center top;

}

h4, h6{
 text-align: right;
 font-style: italic; 
}

h3{
 text-align: center;
 font-weight: bold;
 font-style: italic; 
 text-decoration: underline;
}

h1{
 text-align: center;
 font-weight: bold;
 font-style: italic; 
}

div.lin {
  border-bottom: 2px solid #5bc0de;
}

h5{
color: black; 
}

.btn-group{
margin: 0px;
padding: 1px 1px 1px 1px;

border: 10px;
}

#content1 
{
 height: 100%;
 overflow: auto;
 text-transform: uppercase;
}

#ot{
 padding: 10px;
 border-radius: 25px; 
}

#carousel-example-generic1,
#carousel-example-generic2,
#carousel-example-generic3
{
 margin: 10px;
    float: left;
}

@keyframes animate{ 
from { 
opacity: 0; 
transform: translateY(-100%) 
} 
to { 
opacity: 1; 
transform: unset; 
} 
} 

#pic{
border-radius: 25px; 
animation-name: animate; 
animation-duration: 500ms; 
opacity: 1.0; 
}

.colon 
{
 width: 290px;
 float: left;
 margin: 10px;
 text-align: center;
    border-radius: 25px; 
}

div.colon:hover {
background-color: #b1c6b2;}
```

```html
<html>

<head>

<title>???</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="2hfp1SzUoho7/TsGGGDaFdsuuDL0LX2hnUp6VkX3CUQ2K4K+xjboZdsXyp4oUHZj" crossorigin="anonymous">

<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
<link href="csstitle.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
 <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">
</head>

<body>
<div class="str">
<h1><i>???</i></h1>
<hr />
<a href="title.html"><button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-sm btn-block">Вернуться на главную страницу</button></a>
<hr />

<div id="ingridients">
<h3>Ингредиенты:</h3>

<ul id="one">
</ul>
 
<form id="newItemForm1">
    <input type="text" id="itemDescription1" placeholder="Добавьте описание" />
    <input type="submit" id="add1" value="добавить" />
</form>
    
</div>


<hr />

<div id="prigotovlenie">
<h3>Приготовление:</h3>

<ul id="two">
</ul>

<form id="newItemForm2">
    <input type="text" id="itemDescription2" placeholder="Добавьте описание" />
    <input type="submit" id="add2" value="добавить" />
</form>

<h5 id="ot">Приятного аппетита!</h5>
</div>


<a href="title.html"><button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-sm btn-block">Вернуться на главную страницу</button></a>
</div>

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js" integrity="sha384-THPy051/pYDQGanwU6poAc/hOdQxjnOEXzbT+OuUAFqNqFjL+4IGLBgCJC3ZOShY" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.2.0/js/tether.min.js" integrity="sha384-Plbmg8JY28KFelvJVai01l8WyZzrYWG825m+cZ0eDDS1f7d/js6ikvy1+X+guPIB" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.4/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="VjEeINv9OSwtWFLAtmc4JCtEJXXBub00gtSnszmspDLCtC0I4z4nqz7rEFbIZLLU" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="new recept.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

вот скрипт, который я давно написал. можешь под свои нужды подредактировать...

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Document</title>
 <style>

  body {
   font-family: sans-serif;
  }

  button#myButton {
   background-color: #7cacf9;
   padding: 10px;
   border-radius: 5px;
   border:none;
   color: white;
   box-shadow: 1px 1px black;
  }

  ul {
   padding-left: 20px;
  }

  ul li {
   padding:10px 0;
   border-bottom: 1px solid lightgrey;
  }
 </style>
</head>
<body>
 
<h1>Todo List</h1>
<form action="" id="myForm">
 <input type="text" style="height: 30px;margin-right: 20px;" id="inputTodoList">
 
</form>


<button id="myButton">Add new item</button>



<ul id="lol"></ul>
<script>
var x = document.forms['myForm'];
 document.querySelector('#myButton').onclick = function () {
  /* body... */
  
  for (var i = x.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
   document.querySelector('#lol').innerHTML += '<li>' + x[i].value + '</li>';

  }
  document.querySelector('#inputTodoList').value = '';

  removeTask();
  
 }

 
 function removeTask () 
 {
  var bzz = document.getElementsByTagName('li');
  for (var i = bzz.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) 
  {
    bzz[i].onclick = function () 
    {
     this.parentNode.removeChild(this);
    }
   
    bzz[i].onmouseover = function () 
    {
     this.style.backgroundColor = '#FBF2EF';
    }
    bzz[i].onmouseout = function ()
    {
     this.style.backgroundColor = 'white';
    }
  }
 }

</script>





</body>
</html>
```